# ReactJS - Thunk - Dispatch 2 events in sync one after another not working

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

I am new to React and finding it difficult to accomplish Thunk. I have read few questions and also guide but am unable to understand it properly.

I know that I have to connect but I am all lost. Please help.

Single dispatch works fine, but the double dispatch does not work at all. No log is printed.

```
handleSubmit(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.isLoading = true;

    // TWO EVENTS needed, first to add new player and then set as bowler
    if (this.state.showAddBowlerTextfield) {

        utilPostJSON(jsonURL + 'add-player.php', {
            name: this.state.bowlerName,
            matchId: this.currState.matchId,
            inningsId: this.currState.inningsId,
            teamId: this.currState.teamBowling.id,
            isBowler: true
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('Success', response);

                this.setState({
                    bowlerId: response.data.id,
                    bowlerName: response.data.name,
                });

                this.dispatchAddPlayerAndAddBowler();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error', error);
            });

        return
    }


    // This needs only one dispatch
    const {store} = this.context;
    this.currState = store.getState();

    store.dispatch({
        type: constants.NEW_BOWLER,
        payload: this.state
    });

    this.props.parentClose();
}

//This function sends two dispatches
dispatchAddPlayerAndAddBowler()
{
    console.log('dispatchAddPlayerAndAddBowler');

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const {store} = this.context;
        console.log('Store', store);

        store.dispatch({
            type: constants.NEW_PLAYER_BOWLER,
            payload: this.state
        });
        store.dispatch({
            type: constants.NEW_BOWLER,
            payload: this.state
        });
    }
}
```

The output of the log is:

```
Success {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
dispatchAddPlayerAndAddBowler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using thunks wrong. Try refactoring `dispatchAddPlayerAndAddBowler`:

```
dispatchAddPlayerAndAddBowler() {
  console.log('dispatchAddPlayerAndAddBowler');

  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Wrong: const {store} = this.context;
    // you don't need to do this dispatch is already there in the first parameter

    dispatch({
        type: constants.NEW_PLAYER_BOWLER,
        payload: this.state
    });

    dispatch({
        type: constants.NEW_BOWLER,
        payload: this.state
    });
  }
}
```

Also you should use `connect` and `mapDispatchToProps` for `handleSubmit`

Comment: I did not understand `connect` and `mapDispatchToProps` Can you please tell me.

`function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {`
  
  return {
    onHandleSubmit:(this.state) => {
        dispatch({
            type: constants.NEW_PLAYER_BOWLER,
            payload: this.state
        })
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: Have you gone through the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)? Once you use `connect` you should get `onHandleSubmit` in your props by using `this.props.onHandleSubmit` and should call it in the last bit of `handleSubmit` instance method by calling `this.props.onHandleSubmit(this.state)`. Also you should not use `this.state` in your handler simply `onHandleSubmit: state => { dispatch({ type: constants.NEW_PLAYER_BOWLER, payload: state }) }`

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late. I had to read and try documents. Thanks a lot for your valued time.